# What URL should I give to clients for SOAP wsdl deployed on API Manager of WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have deployed my SOAP Web Service in API Manager of WSO2 and I'm stuck in what URLs should I give to clients so that clients can generate, see the WSDLs and use it.

API Manager: http://127.0.0.1:8280/addssubs/v1.0.0

XML generated:

[image: XML generated]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always download WSDL and add it an example in SOAPUI

Comment: Dear but you can not give that Downloaded file to the client as this would be very poor approach.

Comment: Dear if you found answer please share it :)

Comment: That is even better :(